# How to connect VS Code via FTP with Remote Workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have embarked on my Visual Studio Code odyssey.
I need to use it to edit files on a remote FTP server.
I installed the [Remote Workspace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vscode-remote-workspace) (vscode-remote-workspace)

Instructions say:

> Create (or update) a `.code-workspace` file and open it by using File >>
>   `> Open Workspace...` in the GUI:
>
> ```
> {
>     "folders": [{
>         "uri": "sftp://my-user:my-password@example.com?debug=1",
>         "name": "My SFTP folder"
>     }]
> }
> ```

like...

> ```
> FTP [↑]
> URL Format: ftp://[user:password@]host[:port][/path/to/a/folder][?param1=value1&param2=value2]
>
> {
>     "folders": [{
>         "uri": "ftp://my-user:my-password@ftp.example.com/",
>         "name": "My FTP folder"
>     }]
> }
> ```

I am trying to set up a connection to my FTP server.

I have:

- Saved Workspace As to create `MySpace.code-workspace` file
- Opens Settings and pasted the following in to Workspace Settings...

`{
    "folders": [{
        "uri": "ftp://myuser:mypass@ftp.myhost.com:21",
        "name": "My FTP folder"
    }
],
"settings": {},
}`

However, the bottom-right of VSCode reports...

[image]

("Can't find remote", "File not found")

... while the sidebar shows...

[image]

(An exclamation mark, with the hint underneath hover: "Can not resolve workspace folder")

I don't get to see any file tree, though I have read [the parallel issue](https://github.com/mkloubert/vscode-remote-workspace/issues/32) about a problem showing files below top level.

I wondered if my FTP host has trouble accepting a login with the uri format you advise. Trying to login to it via Mac Terminal with `myuser:mypass@ftp.myhost.com:21`, it actually reports: `331 User myuser:mypass OK. Password required`, which is obviously wrong. It took removing the password and port to login to it via Terminal. But doing so in Code Workspace Settings doesn't work either.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Back to Atom, I guess.

Comment: Try `sftp` like this: `"sftp://polaris:polaris@192.168.137.130/home/polaris"`

Comment: There is a good explanation here https://www.tutsplanet.com/add-ftp-sftp-in-visual-studio-code/

Comment: I managed to get a different one working https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp - the only one I have.

Comment: The [SFTP extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Natizyskunk.sftp) can do this.

Comment: As of 2023, this updated version of the SFTP extension is the preferred one to use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=satiromarra.code-sftp